# PL/SQL: ORA-00942, error reported in logically unreachable else block. Needed to add EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for it to work. Why?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a PL/SQL script, which executes a few SQL statements if a certain table exists/not exists.

For eg:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER := 0;
  cnt_2 NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables where TABLE_NAME='DOES_NOT_EXIST';
  IF cnt = 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Table does not exist');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Table exists ' || cnt);
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt_2 from DOES_NOT_EXIST;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

When I execute this, I get below error

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt_2 from DOES_NOT_EXIST;
                                    *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 37:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

But, if I add `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in line 11. Then it works fine.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  cnt NUMBER := 0;
  cnt_2 NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO cnt FROM all_tables where TABLE_NAME='DOES_NOT_EXIST';
  IF cnt = 0 THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Table does not exist');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('Table exists ' || cnt);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt_2 from DOES_NOT_EXIST';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Now it works

```
Table does not exist

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

1. Could you please help me understand why an error is being reported if the `ELSE` block cannot be reached logically?  The `cnt` variable will always be `0`, then, I would assume the `ELSE` block is never reached.
2. How come adding `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` is not producing the error?
3. Does this mean, I should add `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` for all such statements in the `ELSE` block?

I searched on SO and other places but couldn't find an answer. Honestly, I don't know what other search terms to use. All search hits leads to generic errors. So, I am asking this question. If this is already answered, please point me to it and close this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that statements are processed in two steps; they are *compiled* before they are *executed*.

During the compilation phase, the identifiers (tables and columns and more) are identified and looked up.  If a table name (or column name or whatever) is not found, then you get a compilation error.

Using `execute immediate` short-circuits this process.  Instead of "executing immediately" this is really "delaying compilation".  The statement is both compiled and executed during run time.  That is why `execute immediate` prevents the error.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is there a better way to code such logics? or Am I stuck with adding `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, in ELSE block for all statements w.r.t to that table ?

Comment: @SantoshSrinivas. . . I don't think there is an alternative if you want to refer to non-existent tables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this:

```sql
select
  owner,
  table_name,
  xmlcast(
    xmlquery(
      '/ROWSET/ROW/CNT' 
      passing xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getXML('select count(*) cnt from "'||owner||'"."'||table_name||'"'))
      returning content null on empty
      )
      as int
   ) as cnt
from all_tables
where owner in ('XTENDER',user);
```

This query returns number of rows for each table from all_tables filtered by your predicates